# PyEnchant with Python 3.4 64 bit on mac?

Tags: python-3.x, pyenchant

Is it possible to install PyEnchant 1.6.x with Python 3.4.x 64 bit on a mac?

When trying to install PyEnchant with pip install, it is installed within the 2.7 version so far.

Did anyone try to use it with version 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

As it seems there is no other way to install PyEnchant (version 1.6.6 is the one most up to date as of now) to download the source codes  at 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyenchant/
and put the unzipped files in the appropriate folder into /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages.

This is because the automated way using pip install pyenchant leads to an install within the folder within version 2.7 so far.